# Retrieve previous version of data frame in R

Tags: r, casting, overwrite, undo

I am new to R. I was working on a data frame TrainData which has 7 columns. While trying to convert column-7 into integer I mistakenly overwrote it with column-6:

```
TrainData[,7]=as.numeric(TrainData[,6]))
```

Is there a way I can get back my original column-7 back? Is there anything similar to UNDO command in R?

Comment: Is it a `factor` or `character` column?.  Also, you can check `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076526/undo-command-in-r`

Comment: Its a character column.
The other post tells about what to do next time. My question was more around - I have already committed the mistake and can I go back on that.
Thanks.